# Plotting forecasted values in R

Tags: r, graph, forecasting, stock, arima

I have intra-minute data,
[Data of the particular stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhghF.png)
I have implmented the code

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)  # For plotting

# Read the CSV file into a data frame (replace 'your_file.csv' with your file path)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/HP Pavilion/Desktop/Time Series Major/BHARTIARTL__EQ__NSE__NSE__MINUTE.csv")

# Extract the time series data (assuming it's in the 'close' column)
time_series <- data$close
print(time_series)

# Check for missing values and handle them if necessary
missing_indices <- which(is.na(time_series))
if (length(missing_indices) > 0) {
  cat("Missing values indices before interpolation:", missing_indices, "\n")
  
  # Impute missing values using linear interpolation
  time_series[missing_indices] <- approx(seq_along(time_series), time_series, 
                                         xout = missing_indices)$y
  
  cat("Missing values indices after interpolation:", missing_indices, "\n")
}



# Use auto.arima to automatically select the best ARIMA model
arima_model <- auto.arima(time_series)
print(arima_model)
print(summary(arima_model))

# Generate forecasts for the next 10 values
forecastedValues <- forecast(arima_model, level = c(95), h = 10)
print(forecastedValues)

# lags = 5, 10, 15
Box.test(arima_model$resid, lag=5, type="Ljung-Box")
```

With the help of ARIMA model, I am forecatsing the values on "close", now I want to do the plotting of forecasted value + original value, but the problem with the plot() function is that it is saying the width of the data(total rows in the data are 370547) is too long, because of which the data is not getting plotted, can anyone help me how to plot such data in graph in R, if it is not possible to draw the intra-minute data, then how to do the averaging per hour, forecasting per hour values and then do the plotting?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Sir, I am unable to get you, but I am guessing you mean the code that can run without errors, The code that I have provided you with, will run without any errors, what I want is to know how to plot such data in R.

Comment: It's not reproducible because you haven't provided the data. The image you have provided is presumably not all of it. Without code that others can run, it is impossible to know what's causing the problem.